# group results in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, filemaker

In my settings table there is a field whose content is:

```
  - Law 1  
  - Law 2  
  - Chemistry 1 
  - Chemistry 2 
  - History 1 
  - History 2
  - Modern language 1
  - Modern language 2
  - Modern language 3
```

(grades)

I wonder if there is an easy way to construct a SELECT sql query that returns:

- Law
- Chemistry
- History
- Modern language

The goal is to filter a portal that shows all teachers in order to show only teachers of a delimited subject.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you are interested in only part of the column, then why do you store it concatenated like this? The best way would probably be to replace that class column with a class ID that links to a class table, which again contains a subject ID linking to a subject table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filemaker supports only a limited subset of SQL. The following might work for you (assuming your numbers never go above 9):

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(YourField, LENGTH(YourField) - 2) 
FROM YourTable
```

> The goal is to filter a portal that shows all teachers in order to show only teachers of a delimited subject.

Not sure how the SQL query will help in this. The proper solution (as already suggested in the comments) is to have two separate fields, one for the subject and one for the ordinal number. Then the task becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear *exactly* what you are asking for.  If you want to remove the last two characters and get the distinct value, you can do something like this:

```
select distinct left(col, len(col) - 2)
from t;
```

All databases support the functionality of `left()` and `len()`; however, the name might be different in the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Sql, you can use substring and charindex to calculate the data dynamically. If you want value before space , suppose for "LAW 1",  if you want to get LAW by identifying the space in between, this will be helpful.

```
with cte as (select 'Law 1'       as Cola union all 
select 'Law 2'       as Cola union all 
select 'Law 3'       as Cola union all   
select 'Chemistry 1' as Cola union all 
select 'Chemistry 2' as Cola union all 
select 'History 1'   as Cola union all 
select 'History 2'   as Cola )

select    substring(cola, 1  ,  CHARINDEX(' ',cola)-1) Calculated_value   from cte
group by  substring(cola, 1  ,  CHARINDEX(' ',cola)-1);
```

Output:

```
Calculated_value
Chemistry
History
Law
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this requirement depends on the database that you use.
This is for MySql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  TRIM(TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1) FROM col)) grouped_col
FROM tablename
```

This query removes everything after the last space of the value of the column `col` (change it to the actual name of the column), and finally returns all the distinct values of the column.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oHAKpS59oEjU3PYSXnysBc/1).
Results:

```
| grouped_col     |
| --------------- |
| Law             |
| Chemistry       |
| History         |
| Modern language |
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the unwanted chars substrings and select `distinct` as I din see you want some aggregates in your query by grouping.

If you want grouping and aggregation too use below `output` column in group by as well and remove `distinct`

```
  Select distinct REPLACE(column, 
     SUBSTR(COLUMN, 
     INSTR(COLUMN, ' '), 
       LENGTH(COLUMN)) 
      , "" ) as output FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that will extract everything before the last occurrence of the space character is what I think you need. Give this a try..

**SQL Server**

```
select distinct left(col, len(col) - charindex(' ', reverse(col))) as subject
from your_table;
```

**MySQL**

```
select distinct left(col, length(col) - locate(' ', reverse(col))) as subject
from your_table;
```